# Ionic limit API calls

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, limit

I'm using Spotify's API in Ionic using a 3rd party library (I'm not doing HTTP queries directly from my code) and I'm trying to limit how many requests per second I'm sending.

My expectation:

- either I will be able to set a delay for each request
- or to set a maximum allowed requests per second and when I need to send more than the maximum allowed requests per second (which will be a number set by me) this piece of code (library, my code etc) will queue the requests and send them later.

I'm not an expert in Ionic, nor Angular.
I tried this:

```
const apiCalls = [];

//in a for loop
apiCalls.push(fromPromise(this.spotifyApi.getArtistRelatedArtists(sourceArtist.mbid)).delay(this.apiDelay).toPromise());

//then
concat(...apiCalls).subscribe(
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect, for example I sent 20 requests with an apiDelay of 1 second and they were all finished in less than 2 seconds.

I tried using libraries, like this one:
[simple-rate-limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter)
But they are meant to be used with 'require' and Ionic complains that:

> Could not find a declaration file for module

How can I delay requests to an external API in Ionic?

Comment: are requests queued or thrown away if limited?

Comment: The requests should be queued. Basically if I need to do 10 API calls and the API only lets me do 5 calls per second, then the associated Promise for this task should return after at least 2 seconds.

Comment: if you have 10 clients using your app at the same time, how can you set limit for each client?

Comment: API limits are usually per client. I'm only interested in limiting the current client's throughput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing my code to something like this.
It basically uses setTimeout to delay the start of the API call.

```
const apiCalls = [];
let i = 0;

//in a for loop
apiCalls.push(this.getRelatedArtistsWithDelay(i * this.apiDelay, sourceArtist.id[this.PROVIDER]));
i++;

//then
concat(...apiCalls).subscribe(

//and the getRelatedArtistsWithDelay function calls the API with a delayed start
  private getRelatedArtistsWithDelay(delay, artistId){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.spotifyApi.getArtistRelatedArtists(artistId).then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        })
      },
      delay)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try the following simple approach, demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-kfnniw

```
// mock some random requests
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => this.httpCalls.push({
    id: i,
    request: this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl)
  }), Math.random() * 5000);
}

// handle queue
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  let toRun = this.httpCalls.splice(0, 5);
  for (let i = 0; i < toRun.length; i++) {
    ((r) => {
      let s = new Subject();
      r.request.subscribe(s);
      this.httpResponses.push({ id: r.id, subject: s });
    })(toRun[i]);
  }
}, 1000);

// in some other places, process actual requests
setInterval(() => {
  let r = this.httpResponses.splice(0, this.httpResponses.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    r[i].subject.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(`finished request ${r[i].id}`);
    });
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned my API calls are not HTTP calls. I'm using a wrapper library over Spotify which internally does HTTP calls. I need to delay the calls to the API and , very important, keep the order of the answers (why I use the concat command). For HTTP I used in the past the 'delay' method in RxJS and there it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Anakin001, what I have shown above is just a simple implementation of queuing tasks and processing them, as you can see from the demo, I am not even using http at all. So you can tweak it and use concatMap or something similar to suit your own needs.

Comment: I will be honest with you, I think I understand most of what you are doing in the example but I don't know how to adapt it to my use case (I am a beginner in Angular). Also, I don't think I want to add this kind of async processing because in my case I know from the beginning the number of API calls I will need to do (setInterval sounds like something I would use for continuous processing). I would love to be able to just give an argument to RxJS's concat so that it executes each task with a delay. I honestly don't understand why my code in the for loop, with the push, doesn't do the job.

Comment: After some testing I came to the conclusion that in my example only the output is delayed with the given amount for all pushed promises, the delay doesn't appy sequentially.

Comment: I changed my code to delay(i  * this.apiDelay) , i being the loop index, but now I need to test that actually the requests are sent delayed or only the output. I would guess that only the output..

Comment: Indeed, it only delays the emission of the output. But I solved it.. it took me some time to figure out how setTimeout works, now it works. Thanks for all the help. I will post my solution here just in case that someone else finds it and might find it useful.

Comment: @Anakin001, setting varying delay does not solve your problem since requests come in randomly.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you might just be dealing a very simple use case, that you are given an array of requests fixed, right? If that is the case, you can simply group them and delay them based on group index.

Comment: Yeap.. it is exactly what I did in the end :) I'm still a beginner, I come from the Java world which is so different. Thanks for all the help.